# How do I add item on array and replace item on array?

Tags: javascript

Write a program that will fill the guest list. Put the guest to the admit if they are invited; if not, put it on refuse.

My code:

```js
const admit = document.getElementById("admit");
const refuse = document.getElementById("refuse");
admit.textContent = "Admit: ";
refuse.textContent = "Refuse: ";
const people = [
  "Chris",
  "Anne",
  "Colin",
  "Terri",
  "Phil",
  "Lola",
  "Sam",
  "Kay",
  "Bruce",
];

for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  if (people[i] === "Phil" || people[i] === "Lola") {
    refuse.textContent += people[i] + ",";
  } else {
    admit.textContent += people[i] + ", ";
  }
}
```

I got the program worked.

```
Admit:  Chris, Anne, Collin,Terri,Sam,Kay,
Refuse:  Phil,Lola,
```

But I'm trying to solve how to add `and` and replace the `,` with `.`.

Here is the output that I want:

```
Admit:  Chris, Anne, Collin,Terri, Sam, Kay, and Bruce.
Refuse:  Phil and Lola.
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const people = ['Chris', 'Anne', 'Colin', 'Terri', 'Phil', 'Lola', 'Sam', 'Kay', 'Bruce'];
const admit = [];
const refuse = [];

for (let person of people) {
  (person === 'Phil' || person === 'Lola' ? refuse : admit).push(person);
}

const toText = (array) => {
  let multipleNames = array.length > 1;
  return `${array.slice(0, -1).join(", ")}${multipleNames ? " and " : ""}${array.slice(-1)[0]}.`;
};

admit.textContent = `Admit: ${toText(admit)}`;
refuse.textContent = `Refuse: ${toText(refuse)}`; 
console.log(admit.textContent);
console.log(refuse.textContent);
```

Comment: There is small issue with this code. Say one of name is not present then it will response like  `Refuse:  and Bruce`

Comment: Also it is doing ` and ${admit.slice(-1)[0]}`` which should be array.slice i guess

Comment: `const toText = (array) => {
  let multipleNames = array.length > 1;
  return `${array.slice(0, -1).join(", ")}${multipleNames ? " and " : ""}${array.slice(-1)[0]}.`;
};`

Answer (score 0):

### You can try below code. Add and and comma conditionally.

```
const admit = document.getElementById('admit');
const refuse = document.getElementById('refuse');
admit.textContent = 'Admit: ';
refuse.textContent = 'Refuse: ';
const people = ['Chris', 'Anne', 'Colin', 'Terri', 'Phil', 'Lola', 'Sam', 'Kay', 'Bruce'];

for (let i = 0; i <= people.length; i++) {
if (people[i] === 'Phil' || people[i] === 'Lola') {
      refuse.textContent += (refuse.length == 1) ' and ' + people[i] : people[i];
  }else{
      admit.textContent += (people.length == i) ' and ' + people[i] : people[i] + ',';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
const admit = document.getElementById("admit");
const refuse = document.getElementById("refuse");
admit.textContent = "Admit: ";
refuse.textContent = "Refuse: ";
const people = ["Chris", "Anne", "Colin", "Terri", "Phil", "Lola", "Sam", "Kay", "Bruce"];
let refusedPeople = [];
let admitedPeople = [];
people.forEach((person) => {
  person === "Phil" || person === "Lola" ? refusedPeople.push(person) : admitedPeople.push(person);
});

const genrateConcatString = (arr, person, index) => {
  let text = "";
  if (index === arr.length - 1) {
    arr.length === 1 ? (text += person + ".") : (text += " and " + person + ".");
  } else {
    index === arr.length - 2 ? (text += person) : (text += person + ", ");
  }
  return text;
};
refusedPeople.forEach((person, index) => {
  refuse.textContent += genrateConcatString(refusedPeople, person, index);
});

admitedPeople.forEach((person, index) => {
  admit.textContent += genrateConcatString(admitedPeople, person, index);
});
```